# Array of images is not showing proper without alert box on canvas with x , y coordinates

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, canvas

I have got image names in loop from XML file using ajax and showing on HTML canvas with X, Y coordinates. But images is not show proper without alert box. Means If I put alert box then it showing fine but if I remove alert box from code then all images showing on last X, Y coordinates. 
My HTML code is -

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"   style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

My JavaScript code is -

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

for (iimg=0;iimg<ximg.length;iimg++)
{
   // here I am getting all below values in each variable

   var callimgdata=ximg[iimg].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   var callout_imageX=xx[iimg].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   var callout_imageY=xy[iimg].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   var callout_imageHeight=xh[iimg].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   var callout_imageWidth=xw[iimg].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

(function(){
   var letterImg = new Image();
   letterImg.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(letterImg, callout_imageX, callout_imageY, callout_imageWidth, callout_imageHeight);
   }
   letterImg.src = sitePath+"ATOM/chapter1/book/"+callimgdata;
})(iimg);

// If I remove below alert then all images showing on last X, Y coordinates But all it is fine when I keep alert here.
 alert(callimgdata+" ,"+ callout_imageX +" ,"+ callout_imageY+" ,"+ callout_imageWidth+" ,"+ callout_imageHeight);
```

Comment: You've got a comma at the end of this line instead of a semicolon: `var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),`. It might trip up the browser and make some of your code not execute.

Comment: Also: could you add the `img` array to make it easier to see the data structure

Comment: @jon Stodle : still same problem after replace semicolon

Comment: My image array is - img/PAGE1_1JPN.PNG,img/PAGE1_2JPN.PNG,img/PAGE1_3JPN.PNG

Comment: please help me guies

Comment: Image loading is asynchronous. By the time the onload handler is called your callout_* vars contains value for the current image, not the loaded image. You need to handle the loop using callback.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".